# How to retrieve id from div id name

Tags: jquery

How can i retrieve id digit from div name?

for example for the following html i would like to retrieve the 123 `<div id="subscript-guest-id-123"></div>`

what i've tried

```
$('[id^="subscript-guest-id-"]').click(function(){
        var sid = this.id.slice().replace('/subscript-guest-id-/','');
        alert(sid);
});
```

Comment: your div doesn't have any name attribute, your question is quite ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
var sid = this.id.replace('subscript-guest-id-', '');
```

That said, storing data like that in the ID is not always the best choice. A better approach could be to store the number in a data attribute:

```
<div class="subscript-guest" data-id="123"></div>
```

And access it:

```
$('.subscript-guest').click(function(){
    var sid = $(this).data('id');
});
```

The benefit of using the data attributes is that you don't have to do any string parsing to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery anyway:

```
$(this).attr('id').replace('subscript-guest-id-', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `substring()`:

```
 $('[id^="subscript-guest-id-"]').click(function(){
            var sid = $(this).attr('id').substring(19);
            alert(sid);
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw8Rb/12/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to find the number:

```
$(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)
```

Another Example : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zrr2q/)

Answer (score 0):

Could be better:

http://jsfiddle.net/H6ZUg/

```
$('[id^="subscript-guest-id-"]').click(function(){
        var sid = this.id.split('-').pop();
        alert(sid);
});
```